# TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable - reshape csv file

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have a csv file where the first column represents numeric ID and a column that represents users comments. 
There are comments that were left out in the ID's column. So, I pretend to check each row in the ID column and if it isn´t numeric, copy that row and paste it in the Comments column (last True in the ID column).print(clean_order): 
web_scraper_order  ... Comments
0                                      1593612265-26203  ...     London is(...)
1                                      1593612270-26346  ...     I don't (...)
2                                      1593612265-26217  ...     Well as for(...)
3                                      1593612290-26579  ...     I sing (...)
4                                      1593612256-26064  ...     Your first (...)
...                                                 ...  ...         ...
3074                                                NaN  ...         NaN
3075  Office of National Statistics website for the ...  ...         NaN
3076                                                NaN  ...         NaN
3077  See the parliament website where you can downl...  ...         NaN
3078  I actually agree with you it's a great shame t...  ...         NaN

clean_order.info():
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3079 entries, 0 to 3078
Data columns (total 16 columns):

## Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype

0   web_scraper_order         2722 non-null   object
1   web-scraper-start-url     2324 non-null   object
2   Discussions_Link          2141 non-null   object
3   Discussions_Link-href     1940 non-null   object
4   Pagination                1820 non-null   object
5   Pagination-href           1757 non-null   object
6   Title_Discussion          1720 non-null   object
7   Published                 1698 non-null   object
8   Published_Date            1679 non-null   object
9   Subjects                  1672 non-null   object
10  Discussions               1660 non-null   object
11  Comments                  1653 non-null   object
12  Pagination_Comments       520 non-null    object
13  Pagination_Comments-href  517 non-null    object
dtypes: object(16)
memory usage: 192.5+ KB

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

clean_order = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/(...)/Page_Clean_test.csv', 'w+', delimiter=';', skiprows=0, low_memory=False)
save_row = 0

for L in range(0, 1500):
     if "159361" in clean_order['web_scraper_order'][L]:
         save_row = L
     else:
         clean_order['Comments'][save_row] = clean_order['Comments'][save_row] + clean_order['web_scraper_order'][L]
```

Error: 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/suiso/PycharmProjects/Teste_SA/Change web_scraper_order.py", line 12, in 
if "159361" in clean_order['web_scraper_order'][L]:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: so your `order` column is an object but it also has `np.nan`s in it, that's probably why you get the error

Comment: When I used your code, this error returned: NameError: name 'np' is not defined. So, I did some research and realized that I had to do is: **import numpy as np**. When I execute the code, another error appeared: **TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len ()**

Comment: My bad it should be `df.web_scraper_order = df.web_scraper_order.fillna('')`... check ou my answer though

Comment: Works well with the `fillna()` code.
Now I just need to copy the remaining column to the comment line. ex: column1: "I was being (...)"; column2: "it did in (...)" in row 915 to the previous ID column.

Comment: I will check vectorized solutions in pandas and give feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution adding `.fillna()` should get the job done. However, it is good to get used to vectorized solutions in pandas. Here is another option.

Start with this data

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['159361' + str(x), 'first comment'] if np.random.choice([True, False])
        else ['comment' + str(x), ''] for x in range(3000)], columns=['ID', 'Comment'])
df.loc[np.random.randint(0, 3000, 200), 'ID'] = np.nan

>>> print(df)
               ID        Comment
0         1593610  first comment
1        comment1
2        comment2
3         1593613  first comment
4        comment4
...           ...            ...
2995  comment2995
2996  comment2996
2997   1593612997  first comment
2998   1593612998  first comment
2999  comment2999

[3000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now group the ID column by getting valid IDs

```
coms = df.groupby(
    df.ID.str.contains('159361').cumsum() # artificial index, increases with every valid ID
    ).ID.apply(list) # returns a list of values for each valid ID

>>> print(coms)
ID
True                          [1593610, comment1, comment2]
2         [1593613, comment4, comment5, comment6, commen...
3.0                                              [15936111]
4.0                                              [15936112]
5.0                                              [15936114]
                                ...
1362.0               [1593612984, comment2986, comment2987]
1363.0                            [1593612988, comment2989]
1364.0    [1593612990, comment2991, comment2992, comment...
1365.0                                         [1593612997]
1366.0                            [1593612998, comment2999]
Name: ID, Length: 1366, dtype: object
```

Now get set the first element of each list as the index and join the rest.

```
coms.index = coms.str.get(0)
coms = coms.str.slice(start=1).str.join('; ')

>>> print(coms)
1593610                                      comment1; comment2
1593613       comment4; comment5; comment6; comment7; commen...
15936111
15936112
15936114
                                    ...
1593612984                             comment2986; comment2987
1593612988                                          comment2989
1593612990    comment2991; comment2992; comment2993; comment...
1593612997
1593612998                                          comment2999
Name: ID, Length: 1366, dtype: object
```

Append to the comments column in df

```
df = df.loc[df.ID.isin(coms.index), :] \ # use only rows with valid IDs
    .set_index('ID') # and set IDs as index so it can be aligned with coms.index
df.Comment = df.Comment + '; ' + coms # join columns

>>> print(df)
ID
1593610                     first comment; comment1; comment2
1593613     first comment; comment4; comment5; comment6; c...
15936111                                      first comment;
15936112                                      first comment;
15936114                                      first comment;
...                                                       ...
1593612984            first comment; comment2986; comment2987
1593612988                         first comment; comment2989
1593612990  first comment; comment2991; comment2992; comme...
1593612997                                    first comment;
1593612998                         first comment; comment2999

[1366 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: I tried the vectorized solutions in pandas and adapted it to my problem and it works well. But, as I said in the comment above; I also need to add the comments that appear in column 2, 3, etc.

Comment: I understand that you also want to do this for more columns. Please note that is not part of your question thus was not considered in my answer. I suggest you post a new question and link to this one as a follow-up. And if you feel this answer satisfies what you asked for in this post you have the option to select as the 'accepted answer' and upvote.

Comment: If you post a follow-up question please include a sample of your data with `df.head(10).to_dict()` and make sure those first rows are representative of your problem. Also please comment here with a link to that new question and I'll be happy to take a look at it. Happy coding!

Comment: Okay, in case I need to create another post to clarify my doubts on this subject, I will forward the link to continue the research. And if I find a solution I will share it with you and the community.
Thank you very much. @RichieV

Comment: I post another question about this subject. If you can help me, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505440/reshape-csv-file-vectorize-groupby-on-different-columns @RichieV